# TDD as a defect-reduction strategy

Tags: tdd

Can TDD be successful as a defect-reduction strategy without incorporating guidance on test case construction and evaluation?

Comment: @smart.java6, why are you deleting the content of your question?

Comment: I can't quite grasp the question, because I don't understand what guidance covers. Is the question really "if developers who don't understand unit testing apply TDD, will that work"?

Comment: TDD can't be successful.. a team may be. However that'd be just luck. A more likely result is that you'd spend a lot of time repeating all the mistakes that led to the creation of the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, my answer would be no.  For TDD to be effective, there has to be guidelines around what is a test and what it means to have something be reasonably tested.  Without a guideline, there may be some developers that end up with tons of defects because their initial tests cover a very small set of inputs,e.g. only the valid ones, which can cause the idea of using TDD to become worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Test driven development can reduce defects in a QA cycle simply because testing allows developers to find defects prior to releasing their code to the QA team.

But without guidance on *how* to test you really won't be able to create any kind of long-term benefit since haphazard testing will only prevent defects by blind luck.  Good tests based on good guidance can go a long way towards reducing defects.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have tests to reproduce defects, how do you know that "defect reduction" has taken place?

of course you *do* have tests - they're just manual, and thus tedious and time-consuming to reproduce...

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a study (warning: link to PDF file)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/esm/nagappan_tdd.pdf) done by microsoft on some of their internal teams.

A quote from it:

> The results of the case studies indicate that the pre-release defect density of the four products decreased between 40% and 90% relative to similar projects that did not use the TDD practice. Subjectively, the teams experienced a 15–35% increase in initial development time after adopting TDD

That's the only actual empirical study done on TDD/Unit testing that I'm aware of, but there are plenty of people (including myself) that will anecdotally tell you that TDD (and unit testing in general) will definitely provide an increase in the quality of your code.

From my own experience, there is definitely a reduction in the number of defects, but the numbers feel like they would be far less than even the 40% from the Microsoft study; This is (again, based solely on what I've seen) primarily because most corporate developers have little to no experience with Unit Testing (let alone TDD), and will invariably do a bad job of it while they are learning. Actually learning how to do TDD well requires at least a solid year of experience, and I've never worked in (or even *seen*) a team which actually had a full complement of developers with that experience.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pickup a copy of Gerard Meszaros' [xUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/index.html).  Specifically, Chapter 5 might apply most directly to your question where it covers the Principles of Test Automation.  Some of those principles that I think apply to your scenario where there needs to be some sort of guidance, common interest, or some sort of implied do this or fear the wrath of :

- Principle: Communicate Intent

  - Tests need to be easy to maintain, readily apparent what the test is doing.
- Principle: Keep Tests Independent

  - Small tests that cover one small piece.  Tests should not interfere with each other.
- Principle: Minimize Test Overlap

  - Need to design tests that cover a specific piece, and do not create tests that exercise the same paths repeatedly.
- Principle: Verify One Condition Per Test

  - This one seemed simple enough for me, but is one of the most challenging in my experiences for people to grasp.  I may write tests that have some multiple asserts, but I try to keep all those together around the specific area.  When it comes to hunting down failures and other test issues, it is MUCH easier to fiddle with a single test that is testing a specific path instead of several different paths all clumped into a single test method.

Further relating to my experiences, if we want to talk about the corporate developer, I have seen some folks that are interested and take the initiative to learn something new, but more often than not, you have folks that like to go with the flow, and like to have things laid out for them.  Without some sort of direction, be it a mandate from a senior engineer-type, or some sort of joint-team discussions (see Practices of an Agile Developer for some ideas such as lunch time meetings once a week), I think your chance of success would be limited.

Answer (score 0):

In a team situation, where your code is likely to be used by someone else, the tests have a fringe benefit that can reduce defects without necessarily even improving anyone's code.

Where documentation is poor (which during development is "often"), the tests act a crib for how you expect your code to be called.  So, even in cases where the code is really very fragile, TDD can still reduce the number of defects raised against the end-product -- by ensuring your colleagues can see well-written tests before they can use your code, you've ensured they know how you intend your code to be used before they call it.  They are thus less-likely to call your code in an unexpected sequence / without having configured something you expected (but forgot to write a check for) as a prerequisite.  Thus they are less likely to trigger the failure condition, and you are less likely to see them or the (human) test team raising a defect because something crashed.

Of course, whether you see that "there's a hidden bug in there, it's just not being called yet" as a problem itself is another good question.